# Mongoose Join List

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and I have two schemas as below

```
contentschema
{ "_id" : autogenerated
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
}

viewedschema
{ "_id" : autogenerated
  "contentid": "ref content",
  "viewedby": "string",
 }
```

All the users who have viewed the content will be stored in the viewedschema collection which has the contentid reference.

Note :As the number of viewed records will be huge, i dont want to have the viewed within the content as embedded document.

In Mongoose, Is there a way to get all the contents (array of content schema) viewed. [Similar to inner join in SQL].

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to merge the documents in two different collections of same database and it performs a left outer join on the collections.

Let us the below documents in `content` collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef51f106b0505f997f84c8"),
        "title" : "myfavoritesong",
        "description" : "A wonderful composition using string instruments"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
        "title" : "myfavoritestory",
        "description" : "An interesting short story with a twisted ending"
}
```

Documents in `viewed` collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef523706b0505f997f84c9"),
        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef51f106b0505f997f84c8"),
        "viewedby" : "user1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52f406b0505f997f84cb"),
        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
        "viewedby" : "user2"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef53c706b0505f997f84cc"),
        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
        "viewedby" : "user3"
}
```

Final aggregate query using $lookup by combining the two collections is

```
db.viewed.aggregate({
    $lookup:{
        from : "content", 
        localField: "contentid", 
        foreignField:"_id",
        as:"viewed_contents"
    }
})
```

Result of the aggregate query for our sample data is

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef523706b0505f997f84c9"),
        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef51f106b0505f997f84c8"),
        "viewedby" : "user1",
        "viewed_contents" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef51f106b0505f997f84c8"),
                        "title" : "myfavoritesong",
                        "description" : "A wonderful composition using string in
struments"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52f406b0505f997f84cb"),
        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
        "viewedby" : "user2",
        "viewed_contents" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
                        "title" : "myfavoritestory",
                        "description" : "An interesting short story with a twist
ed ending"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef53c706b0505f997f84cc"),
        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
        "viewedby" : "user3",
        "viewed_contents" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
                        "title" : "myfavoritestory",
                        "description" : "An interesting short story with a twist
ed ending"
                }
        ]
}
```

Please note you can also swap the collections from `viewed` as foreign and `content` as local

```
db.content.aggregate({
   $lookup:{
     from : "viewed", 
     localField: "_id", 
     foreignField:"contentid",
     as:"contents_viewed_by"
   }
})
```

Result of this aggregate query is as follows

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef51f106b0505f997f84c8"),
        "title" : "myfavoritesong",
        "description" : "A wonderful composition using string instruments",
        "contents_viewed_by" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef523706b0505f997f84c9"),
                        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef51f106b0505f997f84c8"),
                        "viewedby" : "user1"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
        "title" : "myfavoritestory",
        "description" : "An interesting short story with a twisted ending",
        "contents_viewed_by" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef52f406b0505f997f84cb"),
                        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
                        "viewedby" : "user2"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef53c706b0505f997f84cc"),
                        "contentid" : ObjectId("59ef52ad06b0505f997f84ca"),
                        "viewedby" : "user3"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in detail